# access to USB drive broken after changing uid

Tags: permissions, usb-drive, automounting, external-hdd

Since changing my uid I no longer have the permissions to see a USB hardrive/stick that is automatically mounted at /media/USERNAME.

Nautilus gives the message

> Unable to open a folder for DRIVENAME
>
> No application is registered as handling this file

If I log on as root in a terminal I can see that the drive is mounted in the proper location and can access the files.

Does someone know what I need to do to make it so that I can use the mounted drive with my non-root user?

For other users on the system everything works as expected.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.10.

Comment: I think your question is answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/617777/how-do-i-auto-mount-a-usb-drive-that-all-users-can-write-to

Comment: Check the permissions of course.... they are probably still configured for your old uid.  This is one reason why you should never change an account's uid.

Answer (score 4):

On my Ubuntu system it suffices to remove the file /media/username.